# How can one obtain more accurate numerical approximations to an integral involving the floor function in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: integral, numerical-integration, floor, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

After reading sections of the following [book](https://xn--webducation-dbb.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Problem-Books-in-Mathematics-Ovidiu-Furdui-auth.-Limits-Series-and-Fractional-Part-Integrals_-Problems-in-Mathematical-Analysis-Springer-Verlag-New-York-2013.pdf) by Furdui and a [page](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1140833p5357644) on the AoPS forum, I got interested in the integral

[image]

Let's denote the value of this integral by A. Then we have that the value to 20 digits approximately comes down to:

> A = 0.6449340668482264365

However, when one puts in the code

```
integrate 1/(floor(1/x)) from x=0 to 1 to 20 digits
```

In Wolfram Alpha, it generates the following approximation:

> A* = 0.64493701331278272222

As one can see, the numbers start to deviate from one another after the seventh digit. So my question is:

> **Question**: how, if at all, can one obtain more accurate numerical approximations to the value of the integral above in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: How do you know that the first number is more correct than the one given by Wolfram?

Comment: @Nigel Because these digits match pi^(2)/6 - 1 for the first twenty digits - which is the closed form solution to the integral

Comment: May I suggest you use one free mathematica notebook in the cloud https://www.wolframcloud.com/?source=nav  and something like: `NumberForm[NIntegrate[1/Floor[1/x], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1000,WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method->"LocalAdaptive"] ,20]`. You might need to play with the precision and recursion parameters to avoid ending your free trial time.